# how to make methods in beanshell?

Tags: java, android, scripting, beanshell

I made a simple beanshell ide in android using an edittext and a button. When the button is clicked, `Interpreter.eval()` is called and `edittext.getText().toString()` is passed in as the parameter. I want to know: how can I make a method in beanshell and run it?

This is the code i m trying to execute in my beanshell ide:

```
import android.widget.Toast

int i=add(1, 5);
Toast.makeText(context, ""+i, 5000).show();

int add(int i, int j){
    return i+j;
}
```

But i get the following error:

> Command not found: add()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried moving your function definition above its usage, like so;

```
import android.widget.Toast

int add(int i, int j){
    return i+j;
}

int i=add(1, 5);
Toast.makeText(context, ""+i, 5000).show();
```

Does that make any difference?